# How do I position a character at a specific coordinate in a page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried this code:

```
var span = document.createElement('span')
span.style.position = 'absolute'
span.style.color = 'red'
span.style.left = 100
span.style.top = 100
span.innerHTML = '*'
document.body.insertBefore(span, document.body.firstChild)
```

But this code still positions the asterisk at coordinate (0, 0) instead of (100, 100). Here is a jsfiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/E5NDV/

Could you please help me in getting this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var span = document.createElement('span')
span.style.position = 'absolute'
span.style.color = 'red'
span.style.left = "100px"
span.style.top = "100px"
span.innerHTML = '*'
document.body.insertBefore(span, document.body.firstChild)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E5NDV/1/

Answer (score 2):

The values for *left* and *top* should be a *String* giving a number and a unit, e.g. `px` for *pixels*, i.e. `'100px'`. Which child the node is appended as does not matter so much for absolute positioning as this information is not used to decide where to position it, using `appendChild` would work just as well as `insertBefore`.

Comment: They don't _have_ to be in pixels. Any valid unit (e.g. %, px, em) will suffice, but a unit is needed.